# LDAP login module not recognized in web sphere server

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat7, websphere-8

I have been working on jaas ldap authentication of an application. For the development purpose I am using tomcat to deploy the application. When I am deploying the application in tomcat , system is successfully authenticating the user by authenticating the user credentials against a ldap server and authorizing the user by fetching roles from database.

But my problem is when I deploying the application in web sphere server, I am encountering an exception

```
"unable to find LoginModule class: com.enterprise.security.ldap.TrivialLoginModule"
```

I have not included any trivial module in my application

But my application is running fine in tomcat.

```
For my authentication module following classes are defined:
CustomAuthenticationProvider.java
DummyRoleGranter.java
JaasLdapLogin.java

The configuration file is
ldap.jaas.config
```

Could someone please help me in identifying what I am missing for the Web Sphere Server.

My spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.work.application.service.UserDetailsService" />
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationmanager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customauthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/login*" security="none" />

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" default-target-url="/index"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control  max-sessions="1" expired-url="/loginfailed" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
        </security:session-management>
        <security:csrf />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="csrfFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
                    <property name="headerName" value="X-SECURITY" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>



    <bean id="customauthProvider" class="com.work.application.authprovider.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg name="delegate" ref="jaasAuthProvider" />
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
     </bean>

    <bean id="jaasAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.JaasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="loginConfig" value="classpath:ldap.jaas.config" />
        <property name="authorityGranters">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.work.application.authprovider.DummyRoleGranter" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="loginContextName" value="LDAPLogin" />
        <property name="callbackHandlers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.JaasNameCallbackHandler" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.JaasPasswordCallbackHandler" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>   


    <bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="/login"/>        
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.CookieClearingLogoutHandler">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <list>
                            <value>JSESSIONID</value>
                        </list>                        
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ldap.jaas.config

```
LDAPLogin
{
    com.work.application.authprovider.JaasLdapLogin Sufficient
        contextProvider="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
        providerURL="ldap://aeiou:389/dc=app,dc=off,dc=net"
        providerURL_2="ldap://aeiou3:389/dc=app,dc=off,dc=net"
        providerURL_3="ldap://aeiou2:389/dc=app,dc=off,dc=net"
        authenticationMode="simple"
        providerURL_3="ldap://ABCDEFGH:389/"
        providerURL_2="ldap://ABCDEFGI:389/"
        principalPattern="cn={0},cn=Users,dc=app,dc=off,dc=net"
        ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the work around. Since Websphere is not recognizing the config file so instead of using the JaasAuthenticationProvider I used DefaultJaasAuthenticationProvider and injected the configuration in the AppConfigurationEntry Map. It's working fine in websphere now.